# Pyro4 random TimeoutError on receiveData

Tags: python, timeoutexception, pyro4

I've got a connection setup between two PCs using Pyro4, most of the time everything is working seamlessly, however sometimes I can get random TimeoutError like this:

```
    result = self.pyro_proxes[pyro_proxy_name].run_on_pool_controller(*args, **kwargs)
      File "/opt/ute/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/Pyro4/core.py", line 171, in __call__
return self.__send(self.__name, args, kwargs)
      File "/opt/ute/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/Pyro4/core.py", line 410, in _pyroInvoke
        msg = message.Message.recv(self._pyroConnection, [message.MSG_RESULT], hmac_key=self._pyroHmacKey)
      File "/opt/ute/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/Pyro4/message.py", line 168, in recv
        msg = cls.from_header(connection.recv(cls.header_size))
      File "/opt/ute/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/Pyro4/socketutil.py", line 438, in recv
return receiveData(self.sock, size)
      File "/opt/ute/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/Pyro4/socketutil.py", line 149, in receiveData
        raise TimeoutError("receiving: timeout")
```

At first I tought this might be some network related issues, however I checked with ping process in background, and connection is never lost between PCs. I can't really find anything in Pyro documentation about it.

Comment: it is definitely not a network error because network errors starts with  50x.

Comment: Make sure you have given the correct read/write permission and firewall permissions

Comment: @MadhurYadav this can't be the case, connection is working most of the time without any problems.

Comment: @MadhurYadav we're not talking about HTTP here at all, that comment about error codes 50x makes no sense. Pyro has its own wire protocol that runs over raw socket connections.

Comment: @RaStall enable Pyro logging and check the log files. Especially the one on the server. It could be that the server's thread pool is exhausted.  Or there's a programming error that makes the operation take too long. Have you enabled Pyro's timeout setting by any chance?

Comment: @IrmendeJong Yes, i have COMMTIMEOUT set in config to 2 minutes, however operations that are causing this TimeoutError should never take more than 10 seconds to execute. I will turn on logging, and check log files, as proposed